# Distinction between a program and library

Tags: .net, clr, cil

Typically the CLR deals with two kinds of binary:

A program has a file name ending in .exe, is marked as a program in the PE header, and has an entry point.

A library has a file name ending in .dll, is marked as a library in the PE header, has no entry point, and has metadata describing the callable functions it contains.

What parts of this distinction are actually enforced?

For example, I think the extension in the filename doesn't actually matter for anything except the command search path; once the file is being read, the filename is ignored and only the PE header counts. Is this correct?

Can you take a program and treat it as a library, referring to it from another program and calling some of its functions without using its entry point?

Can a library have an entry point? If so, can it be run like a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a .Net class library, add a Main method and rename the output dll to be exe it won't run. As you state, the PE header is not set up correctly for execution. You can treat a .Net program as a .Net library. Ultimately both are just managed assemblies that declare types.

So in summary. Only a managed application can be executed directly. Any managed assembly can be referenced and it's classes consumed (assuming framework version compatibility, type visibility etc)

If you are in this situation however, referencing an exe as a library, it's time to think about splitting out common functionality into a library that many applications can reference. Applications should never need to reference code in other applications.

Answer (score 2):

I know at the very least you can reference .NET executable assemblies from other assemblies as long as they have a usable public API, of course.  I've done this before.

As far as I know, a library cannot be run like a program, though, because, in order to do so, Windows would have to recognize it as an executable which it wouldn't because of its file extension.